# how to upload image using google cloud client library on cloud storage in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, webapp2

i want to upload image on cloud storage. I wrote following code to upload on GCS.

```
class FormHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    # form to upload image
   def get(self):
      upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload',gs_bucket_name='mybucketname')
      logging.info("Upload URL: "+upload_url)
      self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
      self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' %          upload_url)      # ImageUploadHandler
     self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit"
    name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

class ImageUploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
   def get(self, resource):
    self.response.out.write('Uploaded')  

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/image/formHandler',FormHandler),('/image/upload/([^/]+)?',ImageUploadHandler)],debug=True)
```

above code is running and image got uploaded on my bucket with weired name. I want to upload it with a specific name. And how can i access particular image from bucket.

Comment: I'm confused -- why do you subclass your `upload handler` from the *Download* handler?  Anyway, with create_upload_url I don't think you can control the exact name of the GCS object that's created -- you CAN give it a prefix, e.g by gs_bucket_name='mybucket/someprefix', then (if you use a unique prefix) locate and use the datastore BlobInfo entity the upload creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def CreateFile(filename,imageFile):
  with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type = 'image/jpeg') as f:
    f.write(imageFile)
    f.close()

  blobstore_filename = '/gs' + filename
  return blobstore.create_gs_key(blobstore_filename)


class MyImageHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    bucket='youbucketname'
    imageFile = self.request.get('file')
    nameOfFile = self.request.get('filename1')
    fileName = '/youbucketname' + '/' + nameOfFile
    blob_key = CreateFile(fileName, imageFile)
    imageUrl = 'https://%(bucket)s.storage.googleapis.com/%(file)s' % {'bucket':bucket, 'file':naemofFile}
    logging.info("Image-URL " + imageUrl)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/myimagehandler', MyImageHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```